# How to use BSKeyboardControls on Swift project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How can i use this lib which name BSKeyboardControls on swift project?

https://cocoapods.org/pods/BSKeyboardControls

The problem is i don't know how to convert this part

```
[self setKeyboardControls:[[BSKeyboardControls alloc] initWithFields:fields]];
[self.keyboardControls setDelegate:self];
```

into swift.

How to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the code lives inside a view controller that implements the `BSKeyboardControlsDelegate` protocol, we first add a `keyboardControls` property to the view controller to hold a reference to the keyboard controls:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController, BSKeyboardControlsDelegate {

    var keyboardControls: BSKeyboardControls? // Here's our property

    // Remaining view controller code here...
}
```

(It's an Optional, with the trailing question mark, because it will be nil before we set it.)

Then, assuming you have an array called `fields` that contains the fields you're working with, we can translate the two lines in question as follows:

```
self.keyboardControls = BSKeyboardControls(fields: fields)
self.keyboardControls?.delegate = self
```